# How to create a function to be re-used for later within another function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nextForm").on('click',(function(){
        //check criteria
        if(selectedSlots.length < 1 ||$("#positionAppliedFor").get(0).value.length < 1 ||$("#maxAmountOfHours").get(0).value.length < 1){
            //error messages and array          
            var errorForSlots= "<h5>Select at least one availability slot</h5>";
            var errorForPosition = "<h5>Enter the position you wish to apply for<h5>";
            var errorForHours = "<h5>Enter the amount of hours you would like to work<h5>";
            var errors = [];

            //add errors to array
            if(selectedSlots.length < 1){errors.push(errorForSlots)};
            if($("#positionAppliedFor").get(0).value.length < 1){errors.push(errorForPosition)};
            if($("#maxAmountOfHours").get(0).value.length < 1){errors.push(errorForHours)};

            //create message
            var div = "<div id=\"sectionError\">";
            if($("#sectionError").length > 0){$("#sectionError").html('')};
            $(div).appendTo($(this).get(0).parentNode);     
            for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){
            $(errors[i]).appendTo($("#sectionError"));
            console.log(errors[i]);}
            $("</div>").appendTo($(this).get(0).parentNode);    
        } else {
        $("#applicationDetails").slideUp();
        $("#personalDetails").slideDown();
        if($("#sectionError").length > 0){$("#sectionError").remove()};
        }
        console.log("function finished");
    }));
```

It all works perfectly, however, ***I am trying to figure out how to create a function for***

```
//create message
            var div = "<div id=\"sectionError\">";
            if($("#sectionError").length > 0){$("#sectionError").html('')};
            $(div).appendTo($(this).get(0).parentNode);     
            for(var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++){
            $(errors[i]).appendTo($("#sectionError"));
            console.log(errors[i]);}
            $("</div>").appendTo($(this).get(0).parentNode);
```

I am planning to re-use this for few other sections on my form and rather than copy/paste I would like to get some help on making my code tidier.

I did try:

```
function myFunction(){
//message code here
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nextForm").on('click',(function(){
//check criteria
...
//add errors
...
//call func
myFunction();
(I also tried this.myFunction();)
...
}));
});
```

However, that ended up in TypeError and I don't know where to begin...
I am also concerned about the "this" in my message code so I am also not sure how to address that in my new function...

Admitedly I am a newbie at this and I do not exactly understand all the ins and outs, hopefully you will be able to help.

Maybe there is a better way of doing this?
Let me know your thought either way!
Thanks.

Comment: In the part where you said "I did try" should work.  You have the method as a global function outside of any nested method.  So it would be available every where as simply `myFunction();`  This, however, is just saying you did the function declaration correctly, not necessarily that the contents of the function will work.

Comment: Thats what I thought but the function  "myfucntion(){ console.log("test");}" returned the type error. I thought this should be ok?

Comment: Also as a side note: `$(this).get(0)` <= don't do that.  `$(this)` takes the Element that you have, and creates a jQuery object with it as the single element in its stack.  Then `get(0)` turns around and breaks the Element out of the jQuery object, so you have just the Element again.  Don't do that.

Comment: `myfucntion(){ console.log("test");}` is missing the `function` keyword in front of it to denote it is a function definition.

Comment: Also you're appending a few divs with the same id `sectionError`. Are you sure?

Comment: @Taplar RE:$this am I right thinking this only applies to "this" ?  

It suddenly worked, thank you and I manged to get the function call outside act as planned. Thanks again for your input!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I think so, the idea is that the div gets created every time an error occurs and gets removed once the user moves on to the next section. Is there a better way of doing this? Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a small reusable framework same as how jQuery is doing behind the scene to expose reusable functions. I didn't tested the append function properly,I just explaining how you can create your own reusable plugin to reuse across the project.

You can change the parameters and method name that you want to expose based on your functionality.

Also I would suggest you to move this code to a javascript file as a plugin and drag after the jquery script.

```
   (function (global, $) {
        //you can pass the jQuery object in to this IIFE
        var DisplayError = function (elementId) {
            return new DisplayError.init(elementId);
        }

        DisplayError.prototype = {
            appendError: function (errors) {
                var div = "<div id=\"" + this.elementId + " \">";
                if ($(this.elementId).length > 0) {
                    $(this.elementId).html('')
                };
                $(div).appendTo($(this.elementId).get(0).parentNode);
                for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
                    $(errors[i]).appendTo($(this.elementId));

                }
                $("</div>").appendTo($(this.elementId).get(0).parentNode);
            }
        };

        DisplayError.init = function (elementId) {

            var self = this;
            self.elementId = elementId;
        }

        DisplayError.init.prototype = DisplayError.prototype;

        global.DisplayError = global.DisplayError = DisplayError;


    }(window, jQuery));
```

> You can write the code for clear the html  directly in init function to ensure the element is clearing while initialize the instance itself.

You can invoke the method like below ,

```
var displayError=DisplayError("#sectionError")
displayError.appendError(["errorId"])

             or 

DisplayError("#sectionError").appendError(["errorId"])
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Wow! Great input! It is something that I definitely will take away with me, however, this is bit too high level for me, especially, with the prototype thing. I sort of got what is happening here and the calling of the method looks much more readable but it is a long way for me to confidently utilise such code :(

Comment: prototype is same as like inheritance , let's suppose if you expose this plugin to outside , user can override your existing functionality. Just giving an extensibility.

Comment: Once you have create couple of reusable functions you will get familiar with it.

Comment: init is nothing but creating the instance in the framework itself ,so you can avoid the new keyword. new DisplayError("")

Answer (score 0):

**New Function**

```
   function generateMessage(arg1) {
        //create message for each section
        console.log("generating message");
        var div = "<div id=\"sectionError\">";
        if ($("#sectionError").length > 0) {
            $("#sectionError").html('')
        }
        ;$(div).appendTo($(arg1).parent());
        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {
            $(errors[i]).appendTo($("#sectionError"));
            console.log(errors[i]);
        }
        $("</div>").appendTo($(arg1).parent());
    }
```

**Changed old function**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#adbutnext").on('click', (function() {
        //check criteria
        if (selectedSlots.length < 1 || $("#positionAppliedFor").get(0).value.length < 1 || $("#maxAmountOfHours").get(0).value.length < 1) {
            //error messages and array          
            var errorForSlots = "<h5>Select at least one availability slot</h5>";
            var errorForPosition = "<h5>Enter the position you wish to apply for<h5>";
            var errorForHours = "<h5>Enter the amount of hours you would like to work<h5>";
            errors = [];

            //add errors to array
            if (selectedSlots.length < 1) {
                errors.push(errorForSlots)
            }
            ;if ($("#positionAppliedFor").get(0).value.length < 1) {
                errors.push(errorForPosition)
            }
            ;if ($("#maxAmountOfHours").get(0).value.length < 1) {
                errors.push(errorForHours)
            }
            ;
            generateMessage(this);

        } else {
            $("#applicationDetails").slideUp();
            $("#personalDetails").slideDown();
            if ($("#sectionError").length > 0) {
                $("#sectionError").remove()
            }
            ;
        }
        console.log("function finished");
    }
    ));
});
```